# EXTJS ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, extjs

in extjs, i am trying to make the save button to do the following when clicked.
people.java is the controller.

```
   var letssay = function() {
     Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'people.java',
        method: 'POST',                   
        params :{'firstname': firstname},       
        success: function ( result, request ) {
```

What I do is make function letssay and call it under button. But it doesn't respond correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
           handler: function(){
            letssay();
```

Comment: What errors get thrown? What is the scope of `letssay` to the button?

Comment: It just inserts data through people.java which is the servlet

Comment: But you still haven't said HOW it doesn't respond correctly and what's actually wrong?

Comment: Use chrome developer tools console and tell us the error.

Answer (score 1):

Java classes need to be compiled and served via an app server like Tomcat or Jetty.